# how to show and hide the headers and data inside body of a table using angular8

Tags: angular

I am using table binding dynamically from ts file. Now based on click of detail view button, i am able to show and hide the data based on true and false, Now one label must be shown in either one of 2 conditions.
I am trying it in this way, is there any better implementation in which this can be handled. And also for date field i must give date format, how can that be given.

HTML:

```
   <th scope="col" *ngFor="let field of agentListDetails" (click)="sortAgentList(field.param)" [hidden]="(!switchView && (field.param ==='inactiveDate' || field.param ==='dbaname' || field.param ==='agentPhone'))"> {{field.displayName}} 
                                            <i class="{{field.icon}}" 
                                            aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </th>

 <tr  *ngFor="let agent of agentList | paginate: config">
                                    <td *ngFor="let field of agentListDetails" [hidden]="!switchView && (field.param==='agentPhone' || field.param==='dbaname' || field.param ==='inactiveDate')" class="{{field.class}}">
                                        {{agent[field.param]}}
      

                          </td>
```

TS:

```
  public agentListDetails = [
    { param: 'groupAgent', displayName: 'Group Code', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide ', class: 'width125' },
    { param: 'agentCode', displayName: 'Agent Code', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide', class: 'sort width125' },
    { param: 'agentName', displayName: 'Agency Name', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide ' },
    { param: 'dbaname', displayName: 'DBA Name', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide ' },
    { param: 'agentCity', displayName: 'Location', icon: ' ' },
    { param: 'agentPhone', displayName: 'Phone', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide', class: 'width125' },
    { param: 'inactiveDate', displayName: 'Inactive from', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide' },
    
  ];
```

I have 2 buttons:
One is `switchView` and the other is `ShowAll`

```
 public showAll: boolean = false;
 public switchView: boolean = false;
```

So when either one of button is true, i need to show inactiveDate column if not it should be hidden

[DEmo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hutfhn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: So what is the exact issue here?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I had updated with demo

Comment: Can you explain in more clear way . @Bhrungarajni

Comment: ok, in my demo, when i click on switchView, it becomes active and i am able to see extra fields like, dba name, phone number and inactive date, so that is fine, when i click on showALlAgents i must see all the columns. so when both the buttons are active, i must see all 6 columns, when i click on ShowAll agents alone, then i must get only inactive date along with group code, agent code, agency name and location

Comment: is it clear? or shall i explain in detailed way @PushprajsinhChudasama

Comment: Yeah , now its clear . @Bhrungarajni

Comment: thanks, could you guide me, how can this be solved

Comment: so when you click only on `show active tab` , you want to see the four columns - > inactive date , group code, agent code, agency name and location  only . @Bhrungarajni . Is it ?

Comment: yes correct @PushprajsinhChudasama

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using the `ng-container` and instead of tabs i have used buttons which won't matter the output .

**.HTML FILE **

```
<button (click)="showAllAgents()">Show all agents</button> <button (click)="switchViewAll()">switch view</button>
<!-- For radio button -->
<table>

        <ng-container *ngIf="showAll">
            <tr *ngFor="let field of agentListDetails" >            
                <th *ngIf="field.param !== 'dbaname' && field.param !== 'agentCity' && field.param !== 'agentPhone'">{{field.displayName}}</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="switchView">
            <tr *ngFor="let field of agentListDetails" >            
                <th >{{field.displayName}}</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!switchView && !showAll">
            <tr *ngFor="let field of agentListDetails" >            
                <th *ngIf="field.param !=='dbaname' && field.param !== 'agentPhone' && field.param !=='inactiveDate' ">{{field.displayName}}</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>


</table>
```

**.TS file**

```
name = 'Angular';
   public agentListDetails = [
  { param: 'groupAgent', displayName: 'Group Code', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide ', class: 'width125' },
  { param: 'agentCode', displayName: 'Agent Code', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide', class: 'sort width125' },
  { param: 'agentName', displayName: 'Agency Name', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide ' },
  { param: 'dbaname', displayName: 'DBA Name', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide ' },
  { param: 'agentCity', displayName: 'Location', icon: ' ' },
  { param: 'agentPhone', displayName: 'Phone', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide', class: 'width125' },
  { param: 'inactiveDate', displayName: 'Inactive from', icon: 'fas fa-sort-up printHide' },

  ];
  public showAll: boolean = false;
 public switchView: boolean = false;



showAllAgents(){
    if(this.showAll == false){
      this.showAll = true
      this.switchView = false
      console.log("show all agents are true");
    }else{
      console.log("show all agents are false");
      this.showAll = false
      // this.switchView = true
    }

     console.log(this.showAll); 
  }
  switchViewAll(){
     if(this.switchView == false){
      this.switchView = true
       this.showAll = false;
    }else{
      this.switchView = false
       // this.showAll = false
    }


  }
```

Here is the [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kd1155) output

Comment: sorry, i have missed location field, location field should be there in all logics

Comment: but cant it be done by making code small, with the condition i used in the above

Comment: this consumes more lines of code, i wanted that to be less lines of code in html

Comment: yes, that works in the way i wanted but in html i want code to be less

Comment: For less code, i have to make it more complicate and having more lines in html won't affect your execution because of `ng-container` @Bhrungarajni

Comment: Thanks for answer but they expect for less lines of codes, we shall check for ts as well, i will keep this as well, incase not able to fix means we can see this

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote the answer  ? @Bhrungarajni

Comment: I am trying with other methods as well, incase if it dont work then i will accept and upvote your answer

Comment: Did you found the solution ? @Bhrungarajni